# javascript:array to string in javascript:enclosed with single quotes

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var array = ["f","test"];
var string =array.toString();
```

excepted string  `var string ='f','test';`

current value: `f,test`

Comment: please fix the typo and add a bit more info or context

Comment: Writing this question took so much more time than simply googling the answer. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost had it. Try this:

```
array.map(x => "'" + x + "'").toString();
```

Comment: solved but my IDE thrown an error expression expected

Comment: For browser which not support ES6 you should use ES5 syntax  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43651957/4886453

Comment: Try `function(x) {return "'" + x + "'"}` instead of `x => "'" + x + "'"`

Comment: `var s = array.map(function(b) {
                  return "'" + b + "'"
             });
             console.log(s);`  i'v e tried this but it returns  `[ '\'f\'', '\'test\'' ]` also i don't want  backslahses

Comment: These backslashes come from the toString() function and are not actually part of the Strings. They are just used to separate quotes inside the String from String delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names like array and string are probably...akin to bad etiquitte, but I got'chu:

```
var anArray = [ "f", "test" ];
var theString = "'" + anArray.join("','") + "'";
```

Comment: This looks good but when i push to an array a backslash enclosed with it`'\'f\',\'test\''`

Answer (score 1):

Using *ES6* with string interpolation and arrow function.

You can use `join()` or `toString()` to display each item separated by a comma

```js
var array = ["f","test"];
console.log(array.map(x=>`'${x}'`).join(','))
console.log(array.map(x=>`'${x}'`).toString())
```

Comment: plus one for ES6 solution

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Map in JS

```js
var result = ["f","test"].map(function(b) { 
   return "'" + b + "'"; 
}); 
console.log(result.toString());
```

Comment: This looks good but when i push to an array a backslash enclosed with it`'\'f\',\'test\''`

Comment: I updated. It sound strange because i run the console show the result as your expect :)

Comment: try `var newarr = [];   newarr.push(result);  console.log(newarr);`

Comment: @Jabaa I'm not really get your problem :| you stuck with new string array or my proposal print ['\'f\',\'test\'']?

Answer (score 1):

**1. using JavaScript [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method** **:** It will join all elements of an array into a string.

**DEMO**

```js
var array = ["f","test"];

var res = "'"+array.join("','")+"'";

console.log(res);
```

**2. using ES6 [spread(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript) operator :** It allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.

**DEMO**

```js
let array = ["f","test"];

function printString(a,b) {
  var str = `'${a}','${b}'`;
  return str;
}

var res = printString(...array);
console.log(res);
```

**3. using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) method with ES6 syntax -** It creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

**DEMO**

```js
var array = ["f","test"];

var str = array.map(item => "'" + item + "'").join();

console.log(str);
```

Comment: This looks good but when i push to an array a backslash enclosed with it`'\'f\',\'test\''`

Comment: I propose three solutions you can use any one of them. Please mark the answer as correct so that it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want your **ouptut as a string** and not as array and code to be written such that it is supported by all browser (no ES6). So I have tried to keep it as simple as possible:

```
var arrayTest = ["f","test"]
var str  = arrayTest.map(function(obj) {return("'" + obj + "'")}).toString();
```